# ModelViewSet: "this field is required" when POST, field is FK

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This is my current code

Models:

```py
class Author(models.Model):
    a_author= models.CharField( primary_key=True, unique=True, db_column='author_id')
    a_name = models.CharField(db_column='author_name')


class Book(models.Model):
    b_book = models.CharField( primary_key=True, unique=True, db_column='book_id')
    b_name = models.CharField(db_column='book_name')
    b_author = models.ForeignKey(
        Author,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        db_column='book_author_name')
```

Serializers

```py
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.CharField(source='a_author')
    name = serializers.CharField(source='a_name')
    class Meta:
        fields = ('author', 'name')

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    book = serializers.CharField(source='b_book')
    name = serializers.CharField(source='b_name')
    author = serializers.CharField(source='b_author')

    class Meta:
        fields = ('book', 'name', 'author')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        author_id = validated_data.pop('author')
        author = models.Author.objects.filter(a_author=author_id).first()
        validated_data['b_author'] = author
        return models.Book.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Views

```py
class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     serializer_class = BookSerializer

     def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = models.Book.objects
        author = self.kwargs.get('author')
        queryset = queryset.filter(b_author=author)
        return queryset
```

Url

```py
urlpatterns = [
     path('library/<str:author_id>/', BookViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list', 'post':'create'}))
]
```

Currently if I post to `/library/123abc/` with params: `{ 'name': 'test', 'author': '123abc' }`, it will work - a Book record with name=test, author=123abc will be created.

But now I want to take `author` out of the params (since url already has athor id so I don't want to duplicate it again in params) and send just `{'name': 'test'}`, it will return 400 error with message `{'author': 'this field is required'}`. I have tried `author = serializers.CharField(source='b_author', required=False)` but it didn't work.

Is there any way to get around this? I wonder if there is any way to include additional value in django before params value are validated...

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the `author` to be shown but not written, you need to set that field as `read_only`:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    book = serializers.CharField(source='b_book')
    name = serializers.CharField(source='b_name')
    author = serializers.CharField(source='b_author', read_only=True)
```

Next, you'll want the `author` to be saved when creating a `Book`.
For that, you'll have to explicitly provide it to the serializer:

```
class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = BookSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = models.Book.objects
        author = self.kwargs.get('author')
        queryset = queryset.filter(b_author=author)
        return queryset

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        author = get_object_or_404(Author, pk=self.kwargs.get('author'))
        serializer.save(author= author)
```